# Minus sign in siunitx inverse unit does not adapt to font size

Tags: luatex, fontspec, fontsize, siunitx

It appears to me that the minus sign in `ms^{-1}` from `siunitx` does not adapt to the font size. Here are two examples, one at 10pt and one at 12pt:

[image]

I believe the first minus sign is too long. Is it too long, or would more typographically inclined eyes find it fine?

I'm also new to LuaLaTeX, do I need something more to get the correct size?

A MWE:

```
% compile with lualatex
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
Mean speed was \SI{16}{\meter\per\second},
as measured at \SI{-4}{\milli\second}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I simplify `Mean speed was \SI{16}{\meter\per\second}, as measured at \SI{-4}{\milli\second}.` to just `\si{\per\second} \SI{-4}{\second}

\large
\si{\per\second} \SI{-4}{\second}`, I can see a big difference in the sizes of the two minus symbols in the exponent positions. (`\large` increases the base font size by 20%.)

Comment: Off-topic: If you're going to use `Minion Pro` as the main text font, you should probably also use `Minion Pro Math` as the companion math font. Do note, though, that `Minion Pro Math` is a commercial (and fairly expensive) font.

Comment: Thank you @Mico, I believe I was mistaken. Comparing 9pt with 14pt options to memoir, the 14pt version is longer. I don't know why I can't see the difference between 10pt and 12pt. Still, do you also find it oversized in my screenshot?

Comment: @Mico I wasn't aware of Minion Pro Math, thank you. I already have access to Minion Pro thanks to an unrelated Adobe subscription, but Minion Pro Math appears out of budget for a poor PhD student, unfortunately. Do you believe it would resolve my siunitx issue?

Comment: I don't think there's an `siunitx` issue to resolve. About the congruence between text and math fonts -- do give the following a shot: (a) load `unicode-math` instead of `fontspec`, and (b) add the instruction `\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Stix Two Math}` after running `\setmainfont{Minion Pro}`.

Comment: I will try, thank you for your kind help and apologies for my poor question!

Comment: @Anna Really no need to apologise for your question. Compared to the average quality of questions, your question is actually rather good. It contains a MWE, a screenshot of your output and a description of what you perceived as a problem. I would wish all questions would do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(recapping some of the material contained in the comments)

- I don't think it's right to claim that there's no (discernible) difference between the sizes of the "minus" symbols used in superscript positions with `\SI` or `\si`.
- The default math font under LuaLaTeX is `Latin Modern Math`, a clone of `Computer Modern Math`. Unfortunately, `Latin Modern Math` does *not* mesh all that well, aesthetically speaking, with the text font `Minion Pro`. If acquiring `Minion Pro Math` is beyond your budget constraint, consider making do with `XITS Math` -- or, if you prefer somewhat looser spacing, `Stix Two Math`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,
             StylisticSet=2]% % for "swashy z"
            {XITS Math}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\si{\per\second} {\large\si{\per\second} }

\SI{-1}{\second} {\large\SI{-1}{\second}}

\textit{abcxyz}123 $abcxyz123$
\end{document}




% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,
             StylisticSet=2]% % for "swashy z"
            {XITS Math}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\si{\per\second} {\large\si{\per\second} }

\SI{-1}{\second} {\large\SI{-1}{\second}}

\textit{abcxyz}123 $abcxyz123$
\end{document}
```